# Opening RTSP video in VideoView

Tags: android, rtsp, android-videoview, google-tv

I wan't to open a .3gp video that is hosted on a remote server in a VideoView inside my app. The protocol used is RTSP. I keep getting this error:

```
04-07 19:26:32.528: E/MediaPlayer(7358): Unable to to create media player
04-07 19:26:32.536: W/VideoView(7358): Unable to open content: rtsp://v2.cache1.c.youtube.com/CiULENy73wIaHAk-BOiQ3AO9gBMYDSANFEgGUglwbGF5bGlzdHMM/0/0/0/video.3gp
04-07 19:26:32.536: W/VideoView(7358): java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.: status=0x80000000
```

The stream is working and the codec should be supported. Can't locate the problem. I've tried it on a Sony GTV box and on a ICS tablet.

This is the code I'm using:

```
videoview.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(viduri));

        MediaController mc = new MediaController(PlayerActivity.this);

        videoview.setMediaController(mc);

        videoview.requestFocus();

        videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                videoview.start();
            }
        });
```

Does anyone have experience with the same issue? Any solutions? The error message isn't very helpful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I see is that this stream can't be found. Are you obtaining this Youtube video using YouTube Data API?

Comment: Yeah. I'm using youtube API to get the stream URI.

Comment: I can't believe I made this simple n00b mistake... It was a missing internet permission.

Comment: Juhani, your comment about the internet permission helped me unscrew a video player. This n00b thanks you.